# Error when printing output in Xcode (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been working on creating my first app in Xcode and Swift. It is a random number generator where you can enter the minimum and maximum number.

Everything was working totally fine.I mean 100% perfect. Until I added constraints and then it all fell apart. Instead of giving me the number it will just write '...'

My code is

```
@IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var MaxInput: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var MinInput: UITextField!

@IBAction func UIbutton(_ sender: Any) {
    let minNumber = Int(MinInput.text!)
    let maxNumber = Int(MaxInput.text!)
    let randomInt = Int.random(in: minNumber!...maxNumber!)
    let numString = String(randomInt)
    output.text = numString
```

}

Edit: For anyone having the same problem. All it was, was that my constraints were to small for the number!

Comment: Your constraints have probably made the label too small to display the number. Can you show the constraints you added? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much!

Comment: For the sake of good order and completeness of this website, don't edit your question with the solution, it **is** a question. It is completely fine to [answer yor own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if you solved the problem. This site is not only to help individuals solve their problems, but to create a knowledgebase so when people with similar issues will find your question it will be clear how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your constraints are making the label too small to display the random number. In Xcode, when your app is running in Simulator, you can debug view hierarchy to visually locate your views and inspect their size and constraint.

Refer attached image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who answered! You were right that my constraints were too small for the text (for anyone else having a similar problem!)